Which Authentication type is it?
There is a middleware client that should be connecting to Salesforce. When I go into the middleware to establish a connection, it asks whether I should connect to Sandbox or Production. I select it and punch in my username and password and the connection is established. What kind of authentication is it: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_flows.htm&language=en_US&type=5
Does it last forever? Usually, we need a connected app for the client to connect to Salesforce. In this case, it is possible without a connected app. Why is that?

Do you see a "consent screen" (something with confirm/deny buttons) after entering your credentials?

Yes I see the consent screen

Given that you're entering credentials and getting a consent screen, it's definitely going through one of the "interactive" OAuth 2.0 flows (as opposed to a "headless" flow). It's probably the "Web-Server flow" (a.k.a. the authorization code flow).
The middleware almost certainly has its own Connected App that the company providing the middleware controls. Connected Apps can be "installed" in other orgs, and that happens automatically when you give your credentials/consent for the first time (for a given middleware/application). If you've ever used the Salesforce-provided Dataloader, that's exactly what happens there too.
The access token that the middleware gets from the OAuth 2.0 flow does not last forever. An access token is basically the same as a normal session that you'd have if you logged into your org directly. It times out according to your org's policies, and the timeout is refreshed if you make a call using that token in the last half of the valid period (i.e. if you get a token at 6 AM with a timeout of 2 hours, making a request at 7:15 AM means the new session timeout is 9:15 AM instead of the original 8 AM)
Some flows, like the Web-Server flow, can return a refresh token. The refresh token is generally long-lived (it can last forever, though configuring it to expire after some time is generally recommended), and is what you (or rather, the middleware you're using) would use to get a new access token if the previous access token has expired. If you don't have to keep going into your middleware and logging into Salesforce again every week, then this is the mechanism that they're using to achieve that.
